# vim map key for maximize window

Tags: gvim

I have used `noremap <silent> ,= <C-W>=` in _vimrc file to map `,=` for equal windows.

Now i need to map <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>|</kbd> for maximizing current window. Help me out here. I am using gvim with windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
noremap <silent> ,_  <C-W>_<C-W><bar>
```

(binding it to <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>)

Comment: i wanted to use pipe character |

Comment: pipe character is typed using shift+\ so needed code for shift :)

Comment: `<bar>` is the pipe character `|`, check out `:help bar` ... or do you mean 'i want pipe to trigger the sequence'?